# c++: stream output operation successful but state not good

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to learn more about stream states and read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) that `good()` returns true if the the most recent I/O operation on the stream completed successfully. I have tried to following which, if I understand correctly, goes against the above statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {

    std::stringstream ss;
    int x;

    ss << "42";
    ss >> x;

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // prints 42 as expected
    std::cout << ss.good() << std::endl; // prints 0, expected 1

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone clarify why the stream state is not good even though the last (output) operation was successful? Thank you

Comment: The stream has realized that it reached end-of-file, so it is not "good" anymore.

Comment: End of steam was encountered during the numeric overload of `>>` see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate

Comment: Thank you all. I was under the impression that eofbit will only be set on the next character extraction (which is what happens when reading from a file).

Comment: @linuxfever You are right, that is what happens with a file. I hadn't noticed this behaviour with stringstreams before, and I'm not sure it is correct. Ideally, you want a stringstream to be a drop-in replacement for a file stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why EOF is not set until the next extraction for a file stream is not because there is any difference in behavior between file/string streams, but because many text editors secretly insert a newline at the end of a file. Try creating a text file with the contents:

```
a
b
```

And then inspecting it with something like `od -c` and you might see:

```
0000000   a  \n   b  \n
0000004
```

Notice the sneaky newline after b. If you insert a newline at the end of your stringstream, you should observe the same behavior.